# javascript - search multiple strings in a sentence

Tags: javascript

Using javascript, I'm running through an array of sentences & searching multiple patterns in each of those(Case insensitive search).

The array contents is as below ( output from firebug)-

```
var names=[
    "SUBSET FULL ACT # - TOTAL",
    "SUBSET  ACT ACTIV - TOTAL",
    "SUBSET ACT ACTIV - AVERAGE 1th LOAD",
    "SUBSET ACT ACTIV - AVERAGE",
    "SUBSET ACT ACTIV - AVERAGE 2th LOAD",
    "SUBSET ACT ACTIV - AVERAGE 3th LOAD",
    "SUBSET ACT ACTIV - AVERAGE4th LOAD",
    "SUBSET ACT ACTIV - MAX",
];
```

Here's what I've tried so far.

```
for (j = 0; j < names.length; ++j) {
    var searchRes = names[j].replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase().search(/'average'|'load'/);
    if (searchRes === -1) {
        doThis = "facr1";
    } else {
        doThis = "facr2";
    }
```

The search result is always `-1` though the pattern exists. I've looked up on the internet & find this is one of the common ways to search strings in javascript.

Could I please request a help from a second pair of eyes to help me spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: The pattern `/'average'|'load'/` does not exist...

Comment: Elclanrs - Thank you for this. My intention is to search either `average` or `load`. Is that not the way to do?

Comment: Not with the quotes, and even if it did exist, how would you know, your `if/else` condition does the same thing either way ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d4151vzs/

Comment: Just updated the question & also fixed the code based on your explanation. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've included quotation marks in your regular expression, but none appear in the string. You want just `/average|load/`. You can also use the `/i` modifier to make the expression case-insensitive if you don't actually care that it's lower-cased, and removing spaces doesn't seem to help accomplish anything, though it could result in a false positive on a string like `"ave rage"`. This is probably all you need:

```
var searchRes = names[j].search(/average|load/i);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use match instead:

```
var searchRes = names[j].toLowerCase().match(/average|load/);
if (searchRes) {
   // match
} else {
   // doesn't match 
}
```